# How to filter events according to some entries in FullCalendar V5?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-5

until recently I used an old version of fullcalendar, (in this case V4) in which to be able to filter events loaded from a database I used the function calendar.rerenderEvents(), this is not in version 5 and I I would like to know if there is any way to be able to filter as I did before, since the possible solutions that I have seen would be either through queries or by working with the event object loaded from the database

Next I will leave an example of how to do to be able to filter with version 4

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>{$conf.titulos.inicial}</title>
    <link id="logonsgs" rel='icon' type="image/ico" href='web/img/produccion.ico' />
    <!-- CSS   -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/material-icons.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/material.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link href='librerias/fullcalendar4.4/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='librerias/fullcalendar4.4/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.2/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='librerias/fullcalendar4.4/list/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='librerias/fullcalendar4.4/bootstrap/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!--  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="librerias/fullcalendar/main.css" media="screen,projection" />-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/dataTables.material.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/jquery-confirm.css" />
    <!--    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" /> -->
    <!--  Scripts-->
    <script src="web/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/dataTables.material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/jsPDF/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src='librerias/fullcalendar4.4/main.min.js'></script>
    <link href='librerias/fullcalendar4.4/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <link href="librerias/fullcalendar4.4/icon.vc" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="mdl-grid ancho-min-500">
        <div class="card mdl-shadow--4dp margen_inferior-20 util-center ancho-liberacion">
            <table background="web\img\imagen2.jpg">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%"><button type="button" id="inici" class="boton_ini"><img
                                    src="web/img/logo_SEKURIT_2020_color@2x-8.png" class="sekurit"></button></td>
                        <td width="32.5%"></td>
                        <td width="25%">
                            <div align="center"><label class="mdl-color-text--white">{$conf.titulos.inicial}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div align="center"><label class="mdl-color-text--white">{$conf.titulos.inicial_2} -
                                    {$conf.botones.inicial_4}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="32.5%"></td>
                        <td width="5%"> <img src="web/img/OPEX_RVB.png" align="left" width="70" height="70"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div><label class="color_letra-negro">Linea</label></div>

                        <div>
                            <select id="Linea" class="mdl-textfield__input ">

                                <option value="" selected></option>
                                <option value="all">TODOS</option>
                                <option value="GT">GT</option>
                                <option value="BKT1">BKT1</option>
                                <option value="BKT2">BKT2</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col">
                    <div id='calendar' class=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col-desktop mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone centro">
                    <br><br>
                    <button id="bot_salir" type="button"
                        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
                        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="mdl-tooltip" data-mdl-for="bot_salir" style="text-transform: uppercase;font-size:12px">
                        {$conf.mensajes.salir_1}</div>
                </div>

                <script>
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                if (dd < 10) {
                    dd = '0' + dd;
                }
                if (mm < 10) {
                    mm = '0' + mm;
                }
                today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;



                let calendar;
                let date_picker;

                let filter_linea = "all";
                let filter_archivo = "all";
                let filter_estado = "all";
                let filter_equipo = "all";
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    var calendarEl = $("#calendar").get(0);
                    let today = new Date();

                    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        plugins: ["core", "interaction", "dayGrid", "timeGrid", "list", "bootstrap",
                            "moment"
                        ],
                        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                        locales: 'es',
                        initialDate: today,
                        timeZone: "local",
                        theme: "bootstrap",
                        showNonCurrentDates: false,
                        height: 900,
                        customButtons: {
                            printButton: {
                                icon: 'print',
                                click: function() {
                                    window.print();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        header: {
                            left: 'prevYear,prev,today,next,nextYear,  printButton',
                            center: ' title ',
                            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,   listDay,listWeek,listMonth,listYear'

                        },
                        views: {
                            listDay: {
                                buttonText: 'DIA'
                            },
                            listWeek: {
                                buttonText: 'SEMANA'
                            },
                            listMonth: {
                                buttonText: 'MES'
                            },
                            listYear: {
                                buttonText: 'AÑO'
                            }
                        },
                        defaultDate: today,
                        navLinks: false,
                        businessHours: false,
                        editable: false,
                        selectable: false,
                        eventLimit: false,
                        lazyFetching: false,
                        eventSources: [{
                            url: "web/calendario/cargareventoGTLIB.php"
                        }, ],

                        eventRender: function(info, event, element, view) {
                            var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                                title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                                placement: 'top',
                                trigger: 'hover',
                                container: 'body'
                            });
                            if (filter_linea !== "all" && info.event.id !== filter_linea) {

                                return false;
                            };
                            var showFacilities, shownumeros = true;

                            var numeros = $('#numero').val();

                            /* filters */
                            if (numeros.length > 0) {
                                shownumeros = info.event.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(numeros) >= 0;
                            }
                            return ['all', info.event.id].indexOf($('#Linea').val()) >= 0 &&
                                shownumeros;
                        },
                        date_picker,
                        weekNumbers: true,
                        eventDisplay: 'block'

                    });

                    calendar.render();
                    //inicio
                    $('#inici').click(function() {

                        $(location).attr('href', 'index.php?acc=login_in');

                    });
                    // SALIR
                    $('#bot_salir').click(function() {

                        $(location).attr('href', 'index.php?acc=calidad');

                    });
                    $(document).on("click", ".FiltLin-container .FiltLin", function(e) {
                        filter_linea = $(this).val();

                        calendar.rerenderEvents();
                    });
                    //visible
                    $('#Linea').on('change', function() {
                        calendar.rerenderEvents();
                    });
                });
                </script>
</body>
<footer>
    <img src="web/img/logosg_m.png" alt="" class="floating-logo">
</footer>

</html>
```

Could something similar be done with V5?

**clarification:**

->What I tried so far was to work with the v4 function in v5 but it gives me an error like it doesn't exist, I also tried to work with the event object showing only those that met the filters but I couldn't find this object. and I would say that the error is from Js, since everything should be in the client

->The error is that calendar.rerenderEvents is not a function, so skip adding the error

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Comment: V4 to V5, `Calendar::rerenderEvents ----> Calendar::render`  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4

Comment: @NicoHaase What I tried so far was to work with the v4 function in v5 but it gives me an error like it doesn't exist, I also tried to work with the event object showing only those that met the filters but I couldn't find this object. and I would say that the error is from Js, since everything should be in the client

Comment: "It gives me an error" - why not add that to your question?

Comment: @NicoHaase the error is that calendar.rerenderEvents is not a function, so skip adding the error

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important details

Comment: @DavidGonzalo have you tried what GrafiCode suggested, based on the upgrade guide? You should also read that upgrade guide and find out what happened to `eventRender`, because that's changed as well. Specifically: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4#event-rendering It's unlikely to work as you want until you amend that, too. Always read the upgrade guide when upgrading!

Comment: @ADyson 
I'm trying to make it work but no, I understand that it's my mistake when it works I'll report it and put it as an answer, thx